# TV show where goo brings images to life

Tags: story-identification

I remember seeing an episode of an anthology horror/sci-fi show back in the ‘80s/’90s where a guy invents some goo that brings images to life.  He tries pouring the goo on a picture of a women in an adult magazine, but he can’t get the ratio correct, so the creations are monsters that he then has to get rid of.  At the end of the episode he seems to have gotten the correct ratio of goo to image figured out, but I feel like there was another twist at that point that I cannot remember.  Does this ring a bell for anyone? I’m trying to find the name of the series and episode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is from **Steven Spielberg**'s **[Amazing Stories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing_Stories_(TV_series))**.

It's the second season episode [**Miscalculation**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511105/) (1986), starring [Jon Cryer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001083/):

> Nerdy collegiate Phil unsuccessfully tries every trick in the book to meet girls.
> Then **he discovers a potion that makes gorgeous magazine pin-ups spring to life.**

[**The Entertainment Nut**](http://theentertainmentnut.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/retro-recaps-amazing-stories-episode-miscalculation/) has more plot details (including the "twist" at the end), and several screenshots to go with it.

[image: 1]

    [image: 2]

    [image]

Answer (score 2):

That's an episode of *Amazing Stories*, "Miscalculation" which first aired in 1986. The episode appears to be available on Netflix.

From tv.com:

> A college student searching for a date accidently spills chemicals on a magazine and conjures up a dog. He tries desperately to create a beautiful woman, but can't quite seem to find just the right mixture.