TV show where a guy finds a liquid that can bring pictures to life
A guy, maybe a college student, gets a liquid that is poured on pictures or magazines and turns the images into reality.
In a scene he pours the liquid on a magazine model but the model is only half a body.
I think is an anthology TV series like The Outer Limits or The Twilight Zone.

This is the episode "Miscalculation" from the TV anthology series Amazing Stories.

"Nerdy collegiate Phil unsuccessfully tries every trick in the book to meet girls. Then he discovers a potion that makes gorgeous magazine pin-ups spring to life. Unfortunately, he can't guess the right ratio to use, so his experiments backfire in a freaky way."


I remember quite vividly seeing it as a kid!

I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot of the 'half-a-body' lady. Good find :-)

If this indeed is the answer, then it is a duplicate of this question.
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67835/tv-show-where-goo-brings-images-to-life/67854#67854
